# Помогите пожалуйста с перебором одномерных массивов php - конкатенация значений

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть неизвестное количество массивов в массиве например

```
Array
(
       

  [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => B
                )

        )
        
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => C
                )

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => D
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => E
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [alias] => F
                )

        )
        
)
```

Вопрос следующий как грамотно организовать перебор каждого значения слева направо чтобы в итоге получилcя массив с такими различными комбинациями типо:

- A
- АС
- АСD
  **... и так далее
  конец типо таков:**
- AF
- F